# error: incompatible types in assignment of 'long int (*)[4]' to 'long int [4][4]'

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build my own `Matrix` type which acts line an standard `C` matrix with multidimensional arrays. So far, this is my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

/**
 * To build it use:
 *     g++ -std=c++11 test_template_initicialization.cpp -o main
 */
template <int width, int height>
struct Matrix
{
  long int _data[height][width];

  Matrix()
  {
  }

  Matrix(long int matrix[height][width]) : _data(matrix)
  {
  }

  /**
   * Overloads the `[]` array access operator, allowing you to access this class objects as the
   * where usual `C` arrays.
   *
   * @param  line the current line you want to access
   * @return      a pointer to the current line
   */
  long int* operator[](int line)
  {
    return this->_data[line];
  }

  /**
   * Prints a more beauty version of the matrix when called on `std::cout<< matrix << std::end;`
   */
  friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Matrix &matrix )
  {
    int i, j;

    for( i=0; i < height; i++ )
    {
      for( j=0; j < width; j++ )
      {
        output << matrix._data[i][j] << ", ";
      }

      output << matrix._data[i][j] << "\n";
    }
    return output;
  }
};

/**
 * C++ Matrix Class
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class
 */
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Matrix<3, 3> matrix;
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;

  matrix[0][0] = 911;
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;

  std::cout << matrix[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << matrix[0][0] << std::endl;

  Matrix<4,4> matrix2 = { 0 };
}
```

When build the last example `Matrix<4,4> matrix2 = { 0 };` I am getting incompatible types error:

```
D:\test_template_initicialization.cpp: In instantiation of 'Matrix<width, height>::Matrix(long int (*)[width]) [with int width = 4; int height = 4]':
D:\test_template_initicialization.cpp:67:29:   required from here
D:\test_template_initicialization.cpp:16:56: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'long int (*)[4]' to 'long int [4][4]'
   Matrix(long int matrix[height][width]) : _data(matrix)
```

The main part of the error is `'long int (*)[4]' to 'long int [4][4]'`. The `long int (*)[4]` is coming from the `matrix2 = { 0 };` and the `long int [4][4]` is my standard class template declaration `long int _data[height][width];`.

Can I fix my `Matrix` constructor, so it can accept this `long int (*)[4]` coming from `matrix2 = { 0 };` initialization call?

Comment: Someone was asking this same question the other day, and I found an answer here on SE, but I can't find it now. There are a lot of them very similar, maybe one of them will give you a clue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687424/incompatible-types-in-assignment-of-int-to-int-2?s=1|281.2630 for starters.

Comment: The specific problem you have here is exactly what the compiler says: you can't convert an `int *` (what you're passing in) to a `long *` (what the constructor takes).  You have other issues that complicate things (for one, you copy constructor won't do what you think it will), but start with getting your types consistent.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that last link I posted past the title. That was totally not what I intended. I meant more like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778847/invalid-conversion-from-int-to-int3-c

Comment: Use eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, with the help of the following links:

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list
2. [Invalid Conversion from 'int' to 'int(*)[3]' c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778847/invalid-conversion-from-int-to-int3-c)
3. [Using multidimensional std::initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858968/using-multidimensional-stdinitializer-list)
4. [Brace-enclosed initializer list constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118025/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-constructor)
5. [C++ Matrix Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class)
6. [Does java have an equivalent to python __call__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474882/does-java-have-an-equivalent-to-python-call)
7. [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)
8. [Return array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function)
9. [When using C headers in C++, should we use functions from std:: or the global namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606023/when-using-c-headers-in-c-should-we-use-functions-from-std-or-the-global-na)
10. [What happened to std::assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124192/what-happened-to-stdassert)
11. [There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941987/there-are-no-arguments-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter)
12. [Optional Template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787208/optional-template-parameter)

Fixed code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int array_width, typename array_datatype=long int>
struct Array
{
  array_datatype _data[array_width];

  Array()
  {
  }

  Array(std::initializer_list< array_datatype > raw_data)
  {
    unsigned int data_size = raw_data.size();
    unsigned int column_index = 0;
    // std::cout << data_size << std::endl;

    if( data_size == 1 )
    {
      array_datatype initial = *(raw_data.begin());

      for( ; column_index < array_width; column_index++ )
      {
        this->_data[column_index] = initial;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      assert(data_size == array_width);

      for( auto column : raw_data )
      {
        this->_data[column_index] = column;
        column_index++;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Overloads the `[]` array access operator, allowing you to access this class objects as the
   * where usual `C` arrays.
   *
   * @param  line the current line you want to access
   * @return      a pointer to the current line
   */
  array_datatype* operator[](int line)
  {
    return this->_data;
  }

  /**
   * Prints a more beauty version of the matrix when called on `std::cout<< matrix << std::end;`
   */
  friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Array &matrix )
  {
    unsigned int column;
    output << "{";

    for( column=0; column < array_width; column++ )
    {
      output << matrix._data[column];

      if( column != array_width-1 )
      {
        output << ", ";
      }
    }

    output << "}";
    return output;
  }
};


template <unsigned int matrix_width, unsigned int matrix_height, typename matrix_datatype=long int>
struct Matrix
{
  matrix_datatype _data[matrix_height][matrix_width];

  Matrix()
  {
  }

  Matrix(matrix_datatype initial)
  {
    unsigned int line;
    unsigned int column;

    for( line=0; line < matrix_height; line++ )
    {
      for( column=0; column < matrix_width; column++ )
      {
        this->_data[line][column] = initial;
      }
    }
  }

  Matrix(std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list< matrix_datatype > > raw_data)
  {
    // std::cout << raw_data.size() << std::endl;
    assert(raw_data.size() == matrix_height);

    // std::cout << raw_data.begin()->size() << std::endl;
    assert(raw_data.begin()->size() == matrix_width);

    unsigned int line_index = 0;
    unsigned int column_index;

    for( auto line : raw_data )
    {
      column_index = 0;

      for( auto column : line )
      {
        this->_data[line_index][column_index] = column;
        column_index++;
      }

      line_index++;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Overloads the `[]` array access operator, allowing you to access this class objects as the
   * where usual `C` arrays.
   *
   * @param  line the current line you want to access
   * @return      a pointer to the current line
   */
  matrix_datatype* operator[](int line)
  {
    return this->_data[line];
  }

  /**
   * Prints a more beauty version of the matrix when called on `std::cout<< matrix << std::end;`
   */
  friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Matrix &matrix )
  {
    unsigned int line;
    unsigned int column;
    output << "{";

    for( line=0; line < matrix_height; line++ )
    {
      output << "{";

      for( column=0; column < matrix_width; column++ )
      {
        output << matrix._data[line][column];

        if( column != matrix_width-1 )
        {
          output << ", ";
        }
      }

      if( line != matrix_height-1 )
      {
        output << "}, ";
      }
      else
      {
        output << "}";
      }
    }

    output << "}";
    return output;
  }
};


void array_tests()
{
  std::cout << "Array tests" << std::endl;
  Array<3, long int> array;

  std::cout << array << std::endl;
  std::cout << array[0] << std::endl;

  Array<3> array2 = {0,0,0};
  std::cout << "array2: " << array2 << std::endl;

  Array<3> array3 = {3};
  std::cout << "array3: " << array3 << std::endl;
}


void matrix_tests()
{
  std::cout << "Matrix tests" << std::endl;
  Matrix<3, 3, long int> matrix;
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;

  matrix[0][0] = 911;
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;

  std::cout << matrix[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << matrix[0][0] << std::endl;

  Matrix<3, 3> matrix2{ {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} };
  std::cout << matrix2 << std::endl;

  Matrix<3, 3> matrix3 = { 3 };
  std::cout << matrix3 << std::endl;

  Matrix<3, 1, long int> matrix4 = { 4 };
  std::cout << matrix4 << std::endl;
}


/**
 * To build it use:
 *     g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
 */
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  matrix_tests();
  std::cout << std::endl;
  array_tests();
}
```

Running this, you get:

```
Matrix tests
{{4200800, 0, -928274330}, {32765, 14354248, 0}, {-1499063668, 0, 24}}
{{911, 0, -928274330}, {32765, 14354248, 0}, {-1499063668, 0, 24}}
0x65fde0
911
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
{{3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}}
{{4, 4, 4}}

Array tests
{0, 1875566066, 0}
0x65fdf4
array2: {0, 0, 0}
array3: {3, 3, 3}
```

Comment: So what's the fix? tl;dr